# FreeCodeCamp (JavaScript) Project Euler 4

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I'm currently trying to find a solution for the Project Euler Problem 4 in Codecamp. This solution is working with 2 digits, but for 3 is gives instead of the correct result 90909 as answer. As I'm still new to JS I'm not able to find the problem. Thx in advance!

```
  function largestPalindromeProduct(digit) {
  var result;
  var a;
  var b;
  if(digit == 2){
     a = 99;
     b = 99;
  }else{
     a = 999;
     b = 999;
  }
  for(var i = 1; i <= a; i++){
    for(var y = 1; y <= b ; y++){
      var calc = i*y;
      var calcString = calc.toString();
      var calcStringReverse = calcString.split('').reverse().join('');
      if(calcString == calcStringReverse){
        result = calc;
      }
      }
    }
  return result;
}


largestPalindromeProduct(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your solution you loop over all values and update the `result` variable if a palindrome is found, **BUT** you never check whether the new palindrome is larger than the currently selected one, which results in the last found palindrome always being returned (90909).

Here's the corrected code:

```
function largestPalindromeProduct(digit) {
    // We'll initialize "result" with a value, as we'll be using it later on
    var result = 0;
    var a;
    var b;
    if (digit == 2) {
        a = 99;
        b = 99;
    } else {
        a = 999;
        b = 999;
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        for (var y = 1; y <= b ; y++) {
            var calc = i * y;
            var calcString = calc.toString();
            var calcStringReverse = calcString.split('').reverse().join('');
            // This is the fundamental change necessary to get it working as intended
            if (calcString === calcStringReverse && calc > result) {
                result = calc;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you want to further improve your code, I'd suggest reversing your loops and returning the first palindrome encountered, which would improve the method's speed.

Comment: Thx for the answer! Help a lot!